# How to write data in excel or csv with different color, size , Font , Bold and Italic format using c#

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I am writing some report in csv ...so for the best visibility i have to write some data in bold style and some data in different color while writing data into csv..i am using below code for writing in csv ..

```
        FileInfo outtxt = new FileInfo(filename);
        //  StreamWriter logline = outtxt.AppendText();
        // initialiseStream();
        StreamWriter logline = new StreamWriter(fs);
        if (f == 0)
        {
            logline.WriteLine("sometext");             
        }
```

So how can we format this.

Comment: CSV is not a text processor format where attributes can be specified (e.g. color). So the answer is you can't. The content of the CSV file must be used by an application. Your problem needs to be solve at this level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, .csv is just a simple text file but you can generate .xlsx files using other libraries available in nuget.

In my opinion [Epplus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) is a really easy to use example.

If you install this package then the following should give you an example you can use to get started:

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Style;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("MySheet");

                ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "Some Bold Text";
                ws.Cells["A1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                ws.Cells["A2"].Value = "Some blue text";
                ws.Cells["A2"].Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.Blue);
                ws.Cells["A3"].Value = "Some Large Text";
                ws.Cells["A3"].Style.Font.Size = 22;

                ws.Cells["A3"].Style.Border.BorderAround(ExcelBorderStyle.Thin, Color.Red);

                ws.Row(3).Height = 23;
                ws.Column(1).AutoFit();

                package.SaveAs(new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\example.xlsx"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem at all. My Pleasure. If you like my solution you can accept it by selecting the big tick  :-)

Answer (score 4):

Urgent or not:

A .csv (Commas Separated Values) is piure text file, it contains fields separated by `,` or `;`.

It is **not possible** to include any formatting in these files.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what your are talking about is `formatting` in excel while displaying the .csv file. CSV is just a plain text file mostly `comma` separate.

If you want to `format` excel, take a look at [Open XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd452407(v=office.12).aspx)
You have to create some `styles` to display in bold and with colors.It's a bit painful route. If you want easy , you might want to take a look at [Closed XML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/)  library. This one does all the hard work for you and you just have to call few methods to get your work done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EasyXLS Excel library](http://www.easyxls.com/net-excel-library) to write both Excel or CSV file, but the CSV file cannot contain formatting, since is just a plain text file format.

To write Excel file use this code sample:

```
ExcelDocument workbook = new ExcelDocument(1);
ExcelTable tableData = ((ExcelWorksheet)workbook.easy_getSheetAt(0)).easy_getExcelTable();
tableData.easy_getCell(0,0).setValue("sometext");
workbook.easy_WriteXLSFile(filename);
```

To format the cell use this sample code:

```
ExcelStyle xlsStyle = new ExcelStyle();
xlsStyle.setBold(true);
xlsStyle.setForeground(Color.DarkGray);
tableData.easy_getCell(0,0).setStyle(xlsStyle);
```

For more details about formatting check this link:
http://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/format-excel-cells.html